# Render html in server side asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, viewengine

I would like to render some data to html file and then return it to user form asp.net core api.

How to do it correctly?
In node.js i used to work with view engines such as mustache an handelbars.

Comment: Just use Razor in the view as usual with ASP.NET?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not familiar with razor. is it the only option(for general knowledge ?

Comment: Razor is ultra popular in .net as ships with many framework integrated features making it worthwhile using (things like here is an action on the controller render the url to it in an <a> tag).

There are other options, but since core is very new most of them do not plug into MVC as a view engine (so you must handle setting the content type,etc).

There are things such as handle bars 

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Handlebars.Net/

Since core is new, you may find it hard to get questions answered if you leave the common set of base tools people tend to use. I'd say try to use razor.